# 3 different code errors

Tags: php, windows, mysqli

i got these 3 errors in my code. how do i fix them?

> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, integer
>   given inD:\hosting....\html\template_signupfunctions.php on line 14
>
> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   null given inD:\hosting....\html\template_signupfunctions.php on line
>   15
>
> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in D:\hosting....\html\template_signupfunctions.php on
>   line 48
>
> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in D:\hosting....\html\template_signupfunctions.php on
>   line 52

here is my code.

```
    session_start();
// If user is logged in, header them away
if(isset($_SESSION["username"])){
    header("location: message.php?msg=NO to that weenis");
    exit();
}

// Ajax calls this NAME CHECK code to execute
if(isset($_POST["usernamecheck"])){
    $db_conx = include_once("php_includes/db_connect.php");
    $username = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['usernamecheck']);
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$username' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
    $uname_check = mysqli_num_rows($query) ;
    if (strlen($username) < 3 || strlen($username) > 16) {
        echo '<strong style="color:#F00;">3 - 16 characters please</strong>';
        exit();
    }
    if (is_numeric($username[0])) {
        echo '<strong style="color:#F00;">Usernames must begin with a letter</strong>';
        exit();
    }
   if ($uname_check < 1) {
        echo '<strong style="color:#009900;">' . $username . ' is OK</strong>';
        exit();
    } else {
        echo '<strong style="color:#F00;">' . $username . ' is taken</strong>';
        exit();
    }
}

// Ajax calls this REGISTRATION code to execute
if(isset($_POST["u"])){
    // CONNECT TO THE DATABASE
    $db_conx = include_once("php_includes/db_connect.php");
    // GATHER THE POSTED DATA INTO LOCAL VARIABLES
    $u = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_POST['u']);
    $e = mysqli_real_escape_string($db_conx, $_POST['e']);
    $p = $_POST['p'];
    $g = preg_replace('#[^a-z]#', '', $_POST['g']);
    $c = preg_replace('#[^a-z ]#i', '', $_POST['c']);
    // GET USER IP ADDRESS
    $ip = preg_replace('#[^0-9.]#', '', getenv('REMOTE_ADDR'));
    // DUPLICATE DATA CHECKS FOR USERNAME AND EMAIL
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE username='$u' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
    $u_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    // -------------------------------------------
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email='$e' LIMIT 1";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
    $e_check = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    // FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
    if($u == "" || $e == "" || $p == "" || $g == "" || $c == ""){
        echo "The form submission is missing values.";
        exit();
    } else if ($u_check > 0){ 
        echo "The username you entered is alreay taken";
        exit();
    } else if ($e_check > 0){ 
        echo "That email address is already in use in the system";
        exit();
    } else if (strlen($u) < 3 || strlen($u) > 16) {
        echo "Username must be between 3 and 16 characters";
        exit(); 
    } else if (is_numeric($u[0])) {
        echo 'Username cannot begin with a number';
        exit();
    } else {
    // END FORM DATA ERROR HANDLING
        // Begin Insertion of data into the database
        // Hash the password and apply your own mysterious unique salt
        $cryptpass = crypt($p);
        include_once ("php_includes/randStrGen.php");
        $p_hash = randStrGen(20)."$cryptpass".randStrGen(20);
        // Add user info into the database table for the main site table
        $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, gender, country, ip,      signup, lastlogin, notescheck)       
                VALUES('$u','$e','$p_hash','$g','$c','$ip',now(),now(),now())";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
        $uid = mysqli_insert_id($db_conx);
        // Establish their row in the useroptions table
        $sql = "INSERT INTO useroptions (id, username, background) VALUES ('$uid','$u','original')";
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
        // Create directory(folder) to hold each user's files(pics, MP3s, etc.)
        if (!file_exists("user/$u")) {
            mkdir("user/$u", 0755);
        }
        // Email the user their activation link
        $to = "$e";                          
        $from = "auto_responder@dragonsdengamming.com";
        $subject = 'Dragons Den Gaming Account Activation';
        $message = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>Dragons Den Gaming</title></head><body style="margin:0px; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;"><div style="padding:10px; background:#333; font-size:24px; color:#CCC;"><a href="http://www.yoursitename.com"><img src="images/logo.png" width="200" height="200" alt="yoursitename" style="border:none; float:left;"></a>yoursitename Account Activation</div><div style="padding:24px; font-size:17px;">Hello '.$u.',<br /><br />Click the link below to activate your account when ready:<br /><br /><a href="http://www.yoursitename.com/activation.php?id='.$uid.'&u='.$u.'&e='.$e.'&p='.$p_hash.'">Click here to activate your account now</a><br /><br />Login after successful activation using your:<br />* E-mail Address: <b>'.$e.'</b></div></body></html>';
        $headers = "From: $from\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
        echo "signup_success";
        exit();
    }
    exit();
}
```

Comment: you need to fix only first one. others are mere consequences. It's basic PHP syntax issue though.

Comment: a hint to all volunteers. its `include`-related problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems the problem happened to be harder to solve than i thought at first.

include doesn't work the way you're using it.
it doesn't return anything but just run the code from included file.
So, most likely you have to run it just this way

```
include_once("php_includes/db_connect.php");
```

and if you have `$db_conx` set in this file - everything would work.

But there are other problems

1. You aren't using prepared statements
2. You are using mysqli, while PDO have to be used instead

Comment: ok but i still get the errors i posted and can not figure out why, i am very new to php.

Comment: fixed the include once but i still have these errors  plus the ones listed above          Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in D:\hosting\10498727\html\template_signupfunctions.php on line 39

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in D:\hosting\10498727\html\template_signupfunctions.php on line 47

Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in D:\hosting\10498727\html\template_signupfunctions.php on line 51

Comment: ok i fixed the include_once but still have the error messages cant figure out how to fix them what am i doing wrong i try changing the parameter to mysql_results and other still get the errror messages or i get fatel ones. could it be that i'm getting the error because there is not data in the database. also none of the data is being put in to the data base by

Comment: $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, email, password, gender, country, ip,      signup, lastlogin, notescheck)       
                VALUES('$u','$e','$p_hash','$g','$c','$ip',now(),now(),now())"; and$sql = "INSERT INTO useroptions (id, username, background) VALUES ('$uid','$u','original')";

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should take a look at the manual on how to set up an database connection:
    http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.query.php

Whats the source of php_includes/db_connect.php?

Comment: db_connect.php code                     $db_conx = mysqli_connect("ddgusers.db.10498727.hostedresource.com", "ddgusers", "KillingMe30@")OR DIE ("Unable to 
            connect to database! Please try again later."); 
// Evaluate the connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}